# Is there an Android runtime available for Antlr 4

Tags: runtime, antlr4

I can use the standard antlr4 runtime for development of Android apps, in my case I only have a Parser, but when I go to package them Lint and proguard complain about missing swing classes and others.

Is there a runtime for Antlr4 that is Android compatible?

Edit: I have put up a [page with the Eclipse Android library project](http://www.forward.com.au/AndroidProgramming/index.html) that contains the Android port of Antlr Lexer V4.2.2.  moded as described below. (http://www.forward.com.au/AndroidProgramming/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a runtime for Antlr4 that is Android compatible?

No, there is not.

Answer (score 0):

Spent some time solving my problem.

i) generated lexer java file from grammar and check correct using standard runtime library

ii) removed runtime library from project

iii) added java files from antlr4 runtime source dir one at a time to resolve compile errors

needed to remove all @NonNull and @Nullable references

commented out code that references javax etc  mainly toString() and tree display methods

added implementations of Arrays.copyOf and binarySearch that Android does not provide to misc.Utils
      and fixed all references in files used.

Removed all references to System.out and System.err (TODO add in Android Log call as needed)

removed unsupported @SuppressWarnings

removed unused imports

The entire atn and dfa runtime packages have been ported to Android API 7 (Android V2.1+)

In misc package omitted GraphicsSupport.java, JFileChooserConfirmOverwrite.java, LogManager.java and TestRig.java

In Utils removes waitForClose and addWindowListener methods added copyOf and binarySearch methods

In tree package ommitted packages gui, pattern and xpath and other classes not need for compile as I only have a lexer in this project. This is were more work is needed for a 'complete' port.

In runtime package omitted ConsoleErrorListener.java (TODO replace with Android Log error listener), 
replaced String.isEmpty() with (String.length() == 0) in DiagnosticErrorListener.java, 
removed compileParseTreePattern methods from Parser as not needed for my Lexer (TODO fix this), 
omitted ParserInterpreter needs ArrayDeque and Deque implementations (TODO fix this), 
in Recognizer removed ConsoleErrorListener.INSTANCE, 
in RuleContext removed save() and inspect() and toStringTree() methods and replace toString() with empty string return.

Result is the port to Android is about 80% complete.

Contact me via www.pfod.com.au if you want the Android library code as described above.